# How does UISplitViewController work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Sorry if this has been posted before, I went through Apple Docs and SO, but couldn't find a good explanation as to how UISplitViewController works.
I ask this because I have certain customizations enabled for my UINavigationBar that are only applied once I push a ViewController onto my UINavigationController:

[image]

I would like the customization to be applied when the screen loads, and I'm not sure where to put it.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and [ask] and rephrase your question to clarify what you need and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UINavigationController and [this](http://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/) can help regarding UISplitViewController. Though I think you have issue with UINavigationBar customization